# ERROR : Invalid "--device-id"

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am facing a problem while running my app from titanium studio. my previous app was running properly but i created new project and then when i try to run my app, it says

```
[ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "AVD"
For help, run: titanium help build
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

here AVD is my android virtual device name. my device is running properly.

Comment: Have you got the solution for it Or still stuck?

Comment: hey did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

### Possible reasons and solutions

#### Bug in the Android SDK

There was a bug in the Android SDK which is already fixed. The fix was released with Android SDK-Tools 22.6.2. Here are some more information from the [Appcelerator Bugtracker](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-6217?focusedCommentId=296041&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-296041).

#### The (real) device doesn't trust your computer

The USB-Debugging is active on you device, so It is displayed in the device list, but the device  doesn't trust your computer. To fix that unplug the device and plug It again. Wait for the trust this computer dialog and click ok.

#### Corrupted / Wrong "run config"

Sometimes it happens that the run configurations gets corrupted or you have added a wrong one. In this case you can delete the configuration under "Run Configuration":

1. Click the arrow with the current device
2. Click on "Run Configuration"
3. Select the not working configuration (e.g. under Titanium Android Emulator)
4. Click on the red "X" Close the dialog
5. and "run" the device again

[image]